# Can GCP object lifecycle back-up data to Coldline or Archive?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to estimate cost for GCP storage. As well as storage, we would want to use the object lifecycle tool to back up everything held in Nearline to Coldline or Archive at specific intervals (while leaving the operational dataset where it is in Nearline).

Looking at the lifecycle documentation I only see SetStorageClass action being described to move data. Can this action also be set to copy (or more accurately, to remove the 'delete' part of the 'move' action)?

Comment: Why do you want to backup the data? The durability of Cloud Storage, and the versioning feature aren't enough for you?

Comment: It is for a cultural heritage org where this kind of replication is quite normal for digital preservation, to ward against accidental or (less likely) malicious deletion. Typically we would have an operational dataset and a preservation dataset.

Comment: 2 solutions: activate the versioning (the built in solution at your issue). Use Cloud Storage data transfer to replicate files in another bucket. If you must keep file for at least a period of time, you can also activate the retention period.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate costs in GCP you can use its [cost calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)

I do not understand what you mean with "removing the delete part of the move action".

If you want to move `object1` from `nearline` to `coldline`. You need to create a lifecycle rule to do that. You are not deleting anything here.

If you want to delete `object1`, you would need to create lifecyle rule with an action of `Delete`.

So delete and move are two different actions in the lifecycle rule configuration.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#actions

Comment: I understood that technically the move operation is a 'copy' of the data to a new tier or bucket followed by a 'delete' of the data in the original location. So I want to be able to remove the delete part of the move operation.

Comment: Tt doesn't copy it afair. It just changes the metadata of the storage tier field
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#key-concepts

Also, I don't see the use case for moving the data to a different storage tier but leaving the original in it's initial storage tier. The point of this is to move data you will not access  to often. But for the sake of it...I guess you could

- Create a Storage Transfer Job to move from bucket A to bucket B
- Have a Lifecycle policy in bucket b to change the storage tier to a colder tier.

With that you could possible achive your end goal.